# How i can Select all rows between two records with specific field values?

Tags: mysql

I have a Journeys table. One of the columns on this table is `EventType` that holds an integer.

`EventType` can only ever be 1, 2 or 3.

How can I make a selection that has the logic:

> Find a record with `EventType` = **3** and then select all records *before it* until you get to a record with `EventType` = **1**.

Basically, this table collects GPS data (**Latitude and Longitude**) for a journey.

> EventType = 1 means Start of Journey
>
> EventType = 2 means Everything between the Start and End of a Journey
>
> EventType = 3 means End of Journey

The table Schema is:

[image: table schema]

MySQL isn't very good (I can do simple Select statements ...etc) but just couldn't think of a way for attempting this.

Comment: define "before". Tables don't have an inherent ordering.

Comment: please post your db schema.

Comment: So you basically want to retrieve all intermediate points of a single journey? Doesn't your table have a column like journeyID? That way it would be as easy as `SELECT * FROM journeys WHERE journeyID = 1 and EventType = 2;`.

Comment: @Paul that wouldn't work, I do not have a `JourneyId`, also I do need the start and end of a journey to be included.

Comment: Then how do identify single events to belong to a specified journey?

Comment: Seems like your data structure is inadequate to represent what you need

Comment: That table doesn't allow for that information. From the table, I can only found out GPS Journey information (start to end) but no way of identifying what the journey was (e.g. from my house to the shop). You might think it is useless, but for what I'm doing with that data, it isn't important to know a specific journey.

Comment: except that now you've stated that you want to identify all the components of a specific journey.

Comment: Fair point. So this can't be done another way?

Answer (score 0):

I would think you could do something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM your_table
WHERE id > (SELECT MIN(id) 
            FROM your_table
            WHERE EventType = 1)
  AND id < (SELECT MAX(id) 
            FROM your_table
            WHERE EventType =3)
```

This may not be the most elegant solution, but from what I tried, it worked.

Comment: I get 0 rows returned.